# How to change only the desktop background, and not login background in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, monterey, login-screen

How can we change the **desktop** background independently of the **login** background in macOS Monterey?

I noticed that the desktop background and login background are linked; when I change the desktop background, the login background also follows (it is changed to the same image). I would like to change desktop background independently of the login background because of the privacy reason.

Terminology

- Login background - Background image before login
- Desktop background - Background image after login